# Глагол "погребить" существует?

Tags: словообразование, морфология, словоизменение

Есть ли в русском или был когда-нибудь глагол "погребить". Ни в одном авторитетном словаре найти такой глагол не смог. Однако на сайте [flyword.ru](http://flyword.ru/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C.html) этот глагол есть. Я хотел написать администрации, но у них нет обратной связи.

Comment: Я не вижу там этого глагола

Comment: Здесь попытка выяснить этимологию "погребения" (склоняются к "погрести" вместо этого слова) https://www.proza.ru/2015/04/28/1291

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смешно: погребить- ассоциация с  "погубить в погребе". Только не смешно, что это слово всё-таки кто-то употребляет, хотя в словарях его нет и быть не может: 
У Ахмеда погибла семья. Страшный сель (грязевой или грязекаменный поток, возникающий в русле горной реки вследствие бурного кратковременного паводка) смел с лица земли весь горный аул и заживо погребил под собой огромное количество людей.
http://www.world-art.ru/cinema/cinema.php?id=14335

А Вы его не здесь ли нашли:  [flyword.ru](http://flyword.ru/)
Лемма: ПОГРЕБИТЬ
Формы слова: погребить, погребю, погребим, погребишь, погребите, погребит, погребят, погребил, погребила, погребило, погребили, погребя, погребив, погребивши, погребь, погребьте, погребящий, погребящего, погребящему, погребящим, погребящем, погребящая, погребящей, погребящую, погребящею, погребящее, погребящие, погребящих, погребящими, погребивший, погребившего, погребившему, погребившим, погребившем, погребившая, погребившей, погребившую, погребившею, погребившее, погребившие, погребивших, погребившими, погребимый, погребимого, погребимому, погребимым, погребимом, погребимая, погребимой, погребимую, погребимою, погребима, погребимое, погребимо, погребимые...

Но ведь это онлайн-словарь, там машина находит слова, а не человек. такими сайтами пользоваться нельзя,нужно нормальные словари смотреть.

Comment: Да, именно там.

Comment: Людмила, поэтому не стал доверять сайту и спросил здесь. Но они должны проверять то, что написано у них на сайте.

Comment: Да зачем Вам это? Не надо никому писать, они же пишут, что доверять таким машинным сайтам нельзя. Там просто закладывается программа со всеми возможными приставками, суффиксами и окончаниями, а машина сама составляет. просто нужно обращаться к сайтам, которым доверяешь.

Comment: Людмила, так я один раз еще писал одному сайту, приводил словари в доказательство, так и не доказал, ошибка осталось. Просто не все знают, что доверять нельзя. Могут воспользоваться и ошибутся.

Comment: *Там просто закладывается программа* - именно так. Причем это желается именно компьютером - подбирается похожий глагол и берется от него парадигма.

Comment: *Но ведь это онлайн-словарь* - это вообще-то онлайн-словари бывают разные. И вполне адекватные, где компьютер не подбирает, а **находит** нужную словарную статью.

Answer (score 0):

Правильная форма совершенного вида к *погребать* - ***погрести***

[словари](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

"Погребить" действительно нету нигде, в указанном вами источнике тоже не нашел. Там вообще нету глаголов. Где вы-то его нашли?

Comment: Я знаю, что правильная форма "погрести". Я спрашивал, есть ли такой глагол или нет.

Comment: На том сайте в поисковике вбейте слово "Погребенный", вам придет этот глагол.